# How to reach find an Image in the Static File

Tags: python, html, django

I have a beginner's question, I have images which are basically arrows, and I have located them in the media folder but I can't reach them and the images are not appearing on the page. I have tried several things like copying the paths but still, there is something incorrect.

The image absolute path is: `C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Project 4.3\media\arrow-left.png`

Here is the Template

```
<img id="slideLeft" class="arrow" src= {% static "media\arrow-left.png" %} >
```

here is the settings:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(
    os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_in_env')]
VENV_PATH = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(VENV_PATH, 'static_root')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

I added `{% load static %}` but the image still didn't appear in the chrome inspection the image location was as follows:`<img id="slideLeft" class="arrow" src="/static/media/arrow-left.png">`

I have tried everything but it is still not working.

Comment: You'll need to post more of how you've set up your django project.  As-is, it's not easy to discern what the issue is.

Comment: @ewong i've added the settings

Comment: What's BASE_DIR?

Comment: @ewong updated post

Comment: can you print out what the final result of  BASE_DIR is?

Comment: you cannot have space at the end here when closing the jinga. change this {% static "media\arrow-left.png" % } to {% static "media\arrow-left.png" %}

Comment: @ngawang13 i added as you said it returned `Invalid block tag on line 18: 'static', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?` so i added `{% load static %}` but the image still didn't appear in the chrome inspection the image location was as follows:`<img id="slideLeft" class="arrow" src="/static/media/arrow-left.png">`

Comment: it should be this ' / ' not this ' \ ' when you are locating in you src.